# Azure Data Factory Copy Multiple Dataset in One Pipeline

Tags: copy, dataset, azure-data-factory

This is the current situation:
In Azure Data Factory i have more and less 59different Dataset. Each Dataset comes from different DAta Lake container and folders. I want to copy these 59 datasets in a single Pipeline inside Data Factory into different SQL tables. Is it possible to just make a single pipeline that reads all the differents 59 datasets and copy them into the sql tables? and how do you that?

I am avoiding to make 59 different pipelines, which make maintaining Data Factory very difficult.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: You need to rethink why you have 59 different datasets.  You can get by with one dataset if they are coming from the same Linked Service (data lake).  Create a control file to drive your pipeline (I typically use json but can be anything) that defines what source goes to what sink and use those values in the pipeline copy activity.

Comment: Thanks for your response @ScottMildenberger. Im trying to use the Get MetaData activity to read file naes in the Data Lake. After that i will use the ForEach activity to read the files and export the data to a another sink.

Comment: If you can determine the sink table name based on the MetaData values then that should work fine.  If not, you can use a lookup to get proper source/sink mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample procedure to copy multiple datasets in a single pipeline.

Create Config table to read the datasets from different containers and different folders.
[image]
Read the config table to get the details with Lookup.
[image]

Get config details from the output of lookup activity and iterate the containers and folders `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
[image]

Create linked service to the ADLS account.
[image]

Parameters were created for Containers, Folders and Files for the source dataset.
[image]
[image]

Values for the parameters were provisioned from the FOREACH to iterate the Containers, Folders and Files.
[image]

Create a parameters with TableName in Sink dataset
[image]

Add dynamic content for TableName parameter with expression `@first(split(item().Files,'.'))` for extracting the file name.
[image]